# How to get the i'th character from utf-8 String in Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, ruby-1.8

Given the following constant:

```
RUSSIAN_LOWERCASE_ALPHABET = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
```

When trying to get one letter:

```
content_tag(:span, RUSSIAN_LOWERCASE_ALPHABET[0])
```

Ruby 1.9.2 does the work as expected (I see the letter in a browser), while with Ruby 1.8.7 (my production environment) I see a number instead (e.g. `320`).

I tried to change this to:

```
content_tag(:span, RUSSIAN_LOWERCASE_ALPHABET[0..0])
```

but it didn't help (I see a question mark in a diamond instead).

How could I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails you have [Multibyte](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html) support, just convert your string to wrapper class from Rails:

```
RUSSIAN_LOWERCASE_ALPHABET = "...".mb_chars
```

and then you can select character with `RUSSIAN_LOWERCASE_ALPHABET[0]`.

Comment: Good to know about the Multibyte support! Thanks a lot!